# Telerik RadGridView + Style + RadDataPager = Cannot find source for binding IsPinned

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, radgridview, raddatapager

Hello SO community :o)

First of all, I am sorry for my english, I know this is not perfect, but I break my back to improve it. :)

I am currently working with the telerik Framework in WPF.

Here is the code (I had to change my variables name)

```
 <telerik:RadGridView Name="GridName" IsPropertyChangedAggregationEnabled="True" EnableColumnGroupsVirtualization="True" EnableColumnVirtualization="True" ItemsSource="{Binding PagedSource, ElementName=PagerName}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsBusy="{Binding IsLoading}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedIsinFromGrid}" Grid.Row="0">
                <telerik:RadGridView.Resources>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type telerik:GridViewRow}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type telerik:GridViewRow}}" >
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="ACTIVE">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GreenRessourceColor}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="DISABLE">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource RedRessourceColor}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Status}" Value="UNKNOW">
                                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource YellowRessourceColor}" />
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </telerik:RadGridView.Resources>
                <telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Header1" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Item1}" />
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Header2" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Item2}"/>
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Header3" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Item3}"/>
                    <telerik:GridViewDataColumn Header="Header4" DataMemberBinding="{Binding Status}"/>
                </telerik:RadGridView.Columns>
            </telerik:RadGridView>
            <telerik:RadDataPager Name="PagerName" Style="{StaticResource CustomDataPagerStyle}" Grid.Row="1" Source="{Binding ItemsListToDisplay}" PageSize="100" IsTotalItemCountFixed="False" />
```

The error:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='Telerik.Windows.Controls.GridView.GridViewRow', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=IsPinned; DataItem=null; target element is 'GridViewPinButton' (Name=''); target property is 'IsPinned' (type 'Boolean')
```

The grid, the pager and the datas are well displayed with the right color, excepte that I have this error inside my VS output.

More information about the usage of this code.

This code is used inside a UserControl, this userControl is wrapped inside a RadPane then it is injected into a RadPaneGroup.

Why am I doing this? Because I am using prism to inject my modules on the fly into the mainRegion as a RadPane

The error occure only when I am moving the pane outside the RadPaneGroup

It is like I messed up with the RadGridView styleRow.

As you can see, I am not using directly the IsPinned property.

Any Idea?

Comment: This particular error is very common for telerik's WPF controls, I saw it many times for different controls, not just pager. I suggest to ask their support about this, or just write on their forum.

Comment: I just did it :) http://www.telerik.com/forums/telerik-radgridview-style-raddatapager-=-cannot-find-source-for-binding-ispinned#Fy0uMHy3cEmSz9FGtdUv5Q

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the same question on telerik forums.

the short answer is : set your RadGridView's GroupRenderMode to Flat

More details:

The logged this question as a Telerik UI WPF bug.

To get more information and code on this bug and how to reproduice it follow this link : [Telerik Forum Binding error thread](http://www.telerik.com/forums/telerik-radgridview-style-raddatapager-=-cannot-find-source-for-binding-ispinned#yasmHvyZS0SK4rMM6bMxtg)

To follow the bug report : [Bug report](http://feedback.telerik.com/Project/143/Feedback/Details/202324-gridview-setting-grouprendermode-to-nested-can-cause-binding-errors-for-gridview)

The answer made by telerik employ is:

> I was able to successfully reproduce the error at my end and have thus logged a new bug report in our feedback portal to which you can subscribe in order to get notified about any changes in its status. As a gratitude for your help, I've awarded you with some Telerik points.
>
> For the time being, you can set your RadGridView's GroupRenderMode to Flat in order to avoid these binding errors.
>
> Regards,
> Dilyan Traykov
> Telerik by Progress